# How to make selected DataGrid row and display each column in different textbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, database, datagridview, textbox

I'm a beginner at learning WPF, Visual Studio 2010. 
I have a `DataGridView` (bind to MS access database)
And I have a few `Textbox` and the purpose of these textboxes are to display the data from the selected row of DataGridView when I double click on it

This is my code

```
Private Sub TasksDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles TasksDataGrid.MouseDoubleClick

   For Each DataGrid In TasksDataGrid.SelectedItem
        Dim ddd As String
        TextBox1.Text = CStr(TasksDataGrid.CurrentCell.Item)
        ddd = TextBox1.Text
         Dim Subject As String = TasksDataGrid.SelectedItem("Subject", ddd).Value.ToString

         Next
```

Am I doing it correctly? Would love to hear some feedbacks, glady appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListView instead of DataGridView in WPF. you can add the MouseDoubleClick event to ListViewItem.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

In code behind you can handle MouseDoubleClick event. like

```
void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
   //your code here
 }
```